# Tinymce injection security

Tags: security, sql-injection, javascript-injection, tinymce-5, x-xsrf-token

I have public editor where users can share notes using `TinyMCE` but I'd like to prevent them of inserting `JavaScript` or `SQL` (any type of scripts) in this editor.

**So my question is: how?**

`Here is my editor code`

```
<script src="{{asset('js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      tinymce.init({
        selector: '.editor',
        toolbar: [
        'bold italic alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent blockquote | removeformat underline strikethrough subscript superscript | hr | link unlink | table',
        'fontselect formatselect fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor'
        ],
        plugins: 'advlist, lists, image, codesample, imagetools, wordcount, link, colorpicker,table,textcolor,hr',
        menubar: false,
        advlist_bullet_styles: 'square',
        advlist_number_styles: 'lower-alpha,lower-roman,upper-alpha,upper-roman',
        branding: false,
        height : 300,
        removed_menuitems: 'tools, insert, view',
        browser_spellcheck: true,
        contextmenu: false
      });
    });
</script>
```

[image: onestrong text]

Answer (score 1):

There is a public class named AntiXSS, you can use this like below.

```
string safeHtml = AntiXss.GetSafeHtmlFragment(html);
```

Usually in your situation, SQL injection will not be a threat due to the SQLi's principal.

Comment: I just add this to my script? How should we test it?

Comment: use this in your backend.  If you want to test, you can try to input something like <script>alet(xss)</script>  when your web service was run.